# Should I raise moderator attention flag if I see 404 link in post?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I just got flag ban, because of too many declined flags and the most of them were informing about 404 links from old posts.

I don't understand where did I go wrong and what should I do with 404 links, because even my flags were declined I see action taken on my reported posts.

Few of them:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1804139/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1803011/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1803319/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1804425/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1801972/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1802242/revisions

18 in total... to be clear, I try to understand how flagging works and in past other 404 flags were marked as helpful and *I have a feeling that declined flags are just because of being annoying.* :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you're casting a moderator flag, you're asking for us to do something that normal members of the community cannot. The action that you want us to perform should also be easy for us to figure out.

What is the exceptional action that you wanted us to take in all these cases? We can't revive a dead link. That then leaves editing to remove the link, finding a new link to put in its place, or deleting the post entirely.

The first two actions are ones that you can take yourself, or you can inform the poster themselves about the broken links. They'd be more likely to be able to find a replacement source than anyone else (I've done this many times when prompted by comments on my answers). You don't need a moderator for this.

Deleting an entire post is reserved for cases where there was no redeeming value beyond the link. In those cases, I recommend making this clear in your flag so that we know what to look for. We'll still usually be able to figure this out from looking at a post, but it's good to make that obvious in the flag itself. Those are helpful flags, and we will delete entirely link-based posts that are now dead, because they then have no further value.

Comment: Thanks, if I understood correct I should raise flag only if post has no value without link, right?

Comment: @gevorg - That's what I'd recommend. There are rare cases where a once-good link is now pointing at a malicious site that we may want to act on quickly, but you can also edit those out yourself when you come across them. Usually, you only need a moderator if you want an entire post removed.

Answer (score 4):

Flagging is intended to make moderators aware of something that you cannot fix yourself.  You can fix broken links yourself.

So rather than flagging for a moderator, you could try to edit the link out yourself, or even better, find a replacement link, such as a new host for the project/blog/article or to a cached version of the page.  Since you have less than 2K rep, and your edits have to be reviewed, you should be very clear in the edit description about what you are doing and why.  Don't just write "fixed link".

And if you can't find a replacement, and the link can't be removed (as it would render the post meaningless), then leaving a comment for the original author advising them of the broken link is about the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you give me an example of content problem that I cannot fix and should raise a flag?

Comment: @gevorg An example is when someone copies another answer without anything new of value. A normal user cannot delete that duplicate, nor is it something another type of flag would resolve.

Comment: Personally, I think that "fixed link" is pretty clear as an edit summary. It implies that the link was broken, but you found a working version. While it might be better to write "replaced broken link with one to new project location", but, I, as a reviewer, always open the link to make sure that it goes to the right place before approving it (I remember hearing that somebody at one point made a number of shady link edits, many of which were approved and I want to avoid that).

Comment: @Laurel "fixed link" is too generic (just like "fixed grammar" which is over used), which is why I cautioned the user against it.  Something like "Replaced broken link with link to new host" would be better.